# Extract only numeric values from input file name as string

Tags: java

I want to extract only the numeric values from the input string. how can i do it please give some ideas.

input string is like this
string str= "03-01-13_16-47-42.Test1001.csv"

I want the numeric values only i.e, 1001

can anybody help me out what pattern should i use and how i can fetch only numeric value?

Comment: Hmm, ain't 03, 01, 13, 16, 47 and 42 also numeric values?

Comment: give your desired/expected out put for 03-01-13_16-47-42.Test1001.csv

Comment: I would use a regular expression... Will the filename always be in the same format?

Comment: @niiraj874u reading the question properly gives you the answer...

Comment: If you'll always have the same format `"[...]TestSomeNumber.csv"`, a combination of `substring` and `indexOf` will do the trick.

Comment: @PrR3, he wants numeric values, ain't 03, 01, 13, 16, 47 and 42 also numeric values?

Comment: Assuming the number you want to capture is always follows by csv you could use this regular expression `([\d]*)(.csv)` and only use the value from the first capture group

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ascii values, the numbers are all grouped so that you could say (pseudocode):

```
if ascii(1st char) is less than 58 and higher than 47 
then NumericString = NumericString + 1st char
```

then repeat for 2nd char etc.

of course this would get all the numeric values as ginz pointed out, but you could always start at a later char rather than starting at the 1st.

Answer (score 0):

when you convert a `char` to an `int` in java, you get its ascii code, and if it is in range [48-57] then it is a number between 0 and 9. you can do this by:

```
String input = <name of the file>; 
String result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
    char currChar = input.charAt(i);
    if(currChar >= '0' && currChar <= '9')
        result += input.charAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If

```
 String str= "03-01-13_16-47-42.Test1001.csv"
```

pattern always remains the same you can use regular expression to get the desired value by

```
    String str= "03-01-13_16-47-42.Test1001.csv";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*Test([0-9]*).csv");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    if(m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String input = "03-01-13_16-47-42.Test1001.csv";
    String delim = "\\D+";
    String[] nums = input.split(delim);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
```

That should work but if you only want the numeric value before the ".csv" i.e. 1001, then you print the last value of the array:

```
    System.out.println(nums[nums.length - 1]);
```